# jQuery Datepicker - Get date on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, hover

I'm using [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#implement) jQuery datepicker and I'm trying to get the value of the date on hover. I see the plugin has a parameter:

`eventName`
`The desired event to trigger the date picker. Default: 'click'`

Since the documentation is very limited, I wonder if there're are other options besides click and if not, how can I use `eventName` to get the value on hover.

Comment: what do you mean by you want to get the value on mouseover? do you want the date picker to appear on mouseover

Comment: I can get the selected date range using the `onChange` callback if the user `clicks` two dates, but I also want to update the dates live as the user scrolls on each date.

Comment: Why are you not using the datepicker built into jQuery? This one looks heinous.

Comment: Any jsfiddle to work on?

Comment: @SSS Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/QgXNn/

Comment: The eventName parameter only specifies which event will make the datepicker show up. The default of 'click' means that when the user clicks the textbox that is set to be a datepicker, the calendar will show up. I didn't see any option that returns the actual value on a specific event, I assume it requires a click to set the value.

Comment: Look at line 735 of the DatePicker script, where it binds the click event to the click function of the DatePicker object. I'm not sure if it's possible, but you could try to modify the plugin itself to bind 'hover' to the click function instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `eventName` option is only used to bind the internal `show` method to an event:

```
$(this).bind(options.eventName, show);
```

You could, in theory, use `hover` to show the datepicker but you'd have to specify `'mouseenter mouseleave'` for the `eventName` option as [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a jQuery shortcut method to bind to `'mouseenter mouseleave'`.

Since you've stated (in comments) that you want the behavior found at [kayak.co.in](http://www.kayak.co.in/), you can mimic this merely by chaining a `mouseenter` handler after the `.DatePicker` call (no change needed to anything else):

```
$('#date').DatePicker({
    // options...
}).on('mouseenter', '.datepickerDays td:not(.datepickerDisabled, .datepickerNotInMonth)', function (e) { // delegating on the mouseenter event which jQuery patches to be a cross-browser event, and only targeting clickable dates
    var target = $(this).children('a'), // cache lookup
        options = target.parents('.datepicker').data('datepicker'), // get DatePicker options
        current = new Date(options.current), // grab the current month/year
        val = parseInt(target.text(), 10), // grab the target date
        hoverVal = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth(), val), // make into an actual date
        hoverDay = hoverVal.getDayName(), // get the short day name
        hoverM = hoverVal.getMonth() + 1, // and month
        hoverD = hoverVal.getDate(), // and date
        hoverText = hoverDay + ' ' + (hoverD < 10 ? '0' + hoverD : hoverD) + '/' + hoverM, // for a formatted text value
        selectedVal = new Date(options.date[0]), // get the selected date (which may just be the initial date without an actual selection or an actual selected date, hereafter "selected")
        selectedDay = selectedVal.getDayName(), // get the short day name
        selectedM = selectedVal.getMonth() + 1, // and month
        selectedD = selectedVal.getDate(), // and date
        selText = selectedDay + ' ' + (selectedD < 10 ? '0' + selectedD : selectedD) + '/' + selectedM, // for a formatted text value
        startDate = $('#startDate').data('lastHovered') || new Date(hoverVal) || selectedVal, // default to: last hovered, current hover, or "selected" date (in that order)
        endDate = $('#endDate').data('lastHovered') || new Date(options.date[1]) || startDate, // default to: last hovered, actual selected date, or "selected" date (in that order)
        startDateSelected = $('#startDate').data('startDateSelected') || $('.datepickerDays .datepickerSelected.first').length > 0, // test whether an actual date was selected
        endDateSelected = !isNaN(options.date[1]) && (options.date[1] - options.date[0] > 86400000), // test whether an end date was selected. end date is set in options when start date is actually selected and is the same day as the selected start date but the time is set to 23:59:59
        selector; // variable to store a selector string
    // no end date has been selectd AND if no start date has been selected, or if it has and the user is hovering over an earlier date, or if the user hasn't selected a date yet
    if (!endDateSelected && (!startDateSelected || (startDateSelected && hoverVal < selectedVal) || hoverVal <= startDate)) {
        selector = '#startDate'; // use the startDate input
        $('#endDate').val(''); // since using startDate, endDate has not been selected. make sure the input is cleared.
    } else if (!endDateSelected){ // otherwise, as long as no end date has been selected
        selector = '#endDate'; // use the endDate input
        $('#startDate').val(selText); // and set the value of startDate back to the actual selected date value
    }
    if (!endDateSelected) { // if the user hasn't picked an end date (which cannot be picked without a start date)
        $(selector).data({ // persist the last hovered date and whether a start date has been selected
            "lastHovered": hoverVal,
            "startDateSelected": startDateSelected // this is necessary as the plugin routinely destroys and recreates the tables that make up the calendars while navigating the calendars
        }).val(hoverText); // set the value of the input to the hovered date
    }
});
```

### Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QgXNn/5/

Comment: Excellent, works great except for one little thing...If I select first and second date once, the first date stops update on hover. Second still updates fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach:

Create a Div for your hover target

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="test">Hover Me</div>
    <div id="datePicker"></div>
</div>
```

On ready, initialize and bind to hover event to open

```
$(function () {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker();
    $('#datePicker').hide();

    $('#content').hover(function () {
        $('#datePicker').fadeIn('fast');
    }, function () {
        $('#datePicker').fadeOut('fast');
    });

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/ZVf48/2/) (couldnt reference your picker so i used JQuery UI)

---

### Update: Check out the new **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/QgXNn/3/)**

I applied my approach to your Fiddle. Now YOUR DatePicker appears when you hover over "Hover Me"  and disappears whencursor leaves. I added:

```
$(function () {
    $('#date').hide();
    $('#test').hover(function () {
        $('#date').show();
    }, function () {
        $('#date').hide();
    });

});
```

-

BTW, I made the DatePicker Dialog disappear on non-hover just for effect. That can easily be changed by removed the adjoining

```
}, function () {
    $('#date').hide();
```

Comment: Sorry I can't change the plugin at this stage. My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/QgXNn/

Comment: @Nimbuz,I didn't mean to suggest you change your plug-in. only that same logic should apply. I will look at your fiddle

Comment: @Nimbuz I adjusted your Fiddle To use my approach. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

See the **edited** **[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/XWB6d/)**, forked from yours.

```
// setting the value of the input field to hovered date
// Note that we're not triggering the "click" event bec. 
// it will cause the onChange event of the datepicker to be fired. 
// Instead, we're setting and resetting the input field value 
$("body").on("mouseover", ".datepickerDays td", function (e) {
    var d = parseInt($(this).text(), 10),
        my = $(this).closest('table').find('.datepickerMonth span').html().split(', '),
        m = $.inArray(my[0], MONTH_NAMES),
        y = parseInt(my[1], 10),
        date = new Date(y, m, d),
        textbox = $('#startDate').hasClass('focus') ? $('#endDate') : $('#startDate');
    textbox.val(getFormattedDate(date));
});

// We set back the input field back to its original value on mouseout
$("body").on("mouseout", ".datepickerDays td", function (e) {
    var fd = $('#date').DatePickerGetDate(false),
        start = getFormattedDate(fd[0]),
        end = getFormattedDate(fd[1]);
    $('#startDate').val(start);
    $('#endDate').val(end);
});

// ----------------------------------------
// HELPER FUNCTIONS & VARS
// ----------------------------------------

var MONTH_NAMES = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    WEEKDAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
function pad0(num) { return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num; }
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) { return ''; }
    var wd = WEEKDAYS[date.getDay()].substr(0, 3);
    return wd + ' ' + pad0(date.getDate()) + '/' + pad0(date.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Wow, almost perfect except one issue...I select a date range, when I try to select the date range all over again, it selects the end date directly.

Comment: I don't actually do any selection. I only reset the input values on mouse over/out. Check your own fiddle. After you select a range; with the next click, it will set both start and end dates. My fork does the same too. Are you sure this code causes that?

Comment: @OnurYıldırım please don't use `<kbd>` tags to style links in your answers. Those tags are used to denote user input, not hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

For your question. I guess you dont want the datepicker to shown on hover but want the values or dates to be shown in the input box on hover. 
If you want the datepicker to be shown on hover try to use 'mouseover' for eventName Attribute of the plugin
Like this

```
$('.inputDate').DatePicker({
    eventName:'mouseover', // This is the event to fire.
    format:'m/d/Y',
    date: $('#inputDate').val(),
    current: $('#inputDate').val(),
    starts: 1,
    position: 'right'});
```

Its not taking the jquery events of hover.

Now for showing the new date in the input tag  when the datepicker elements are hovered. You may need to tweak the plugin itself try to find this line 734. The code is

```
var cal = $(tpl.wrapper).attr('id', id).bind('click', click).data('datepicker', options);
```

Change it to

```
var cal = $(tpl.wrapper).attr('id', id).bind('mouseover', click).data('datepicker', options);
```

As you can see I have used the old mouseover event and not the jquery 'Hover' keyword.
If this works you can also try to add a new options parameter in the plugin say 'callon:click' and set this option when you call and pass it to this line 734.

```
var cal = $(tpl.wrapper).attr('id', id).bind(options.callon, click).data('datepicker', options);
```

Using this you can set your own events to call for updating the value of the text box. 
It would surely work for a single date picker. Please try it and comment on this. But you may have to manipulate more to set the date on click as well.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't seem to work well with a date range calendar that I want: http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/QgXNn/

Comment: @Nimbuz As I was reading the plugin. They have managed all click events in a single function call. So if you apply mouseover that gets applied to many elements as well.

Comment: And Just wanted to know. How are you planning to show range on hover. Range is generally click event related. If I hover and change the input box then its bound to call onChange function right. Instead if you mouseover then this event should be disabled while finding range. Also I see many answers have popped up on similar lines based on my anwser. Thats surprising

Comment: I need the dates in the input fields to change on hover. Please see kayak.co.in .. if you hover on a date its updated in the input field.

Comment: Why dont you use the same js then?

Comment: ah, thats a much better plugin, wish I knew before.

Comment: @Nimbuzz Hope you get some help with it. Enjoy. BTW it doesnt give you the full functionality of it. But that can be changed from the js if you research a bit on it

Answer (score 1):

Since the plugin already has bound the `change` functions on a `click`, we can use that by attaching an event for `hover` and simply triggering that. So something like:

```
function make_hover(){
    $(".datepickerDays td span").hover(function(e){
        $(this).trigger("click")
    })
    $(".datepickerDays td").mouseup(function(e){
        $('#inputDate').DatePickerHide(); //hide it when click actually occurs
    })
    $(".datepickerContainer").mouseup(function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
          make_hover()
        },0) //have to run this with setTimeout to force it to run after DOM changes
    })
}

var date=$('#inputDate').DatePicker({
    format:'m/d/Y', 
    date: $('#inputDate').val(),
    current: $('#inputDate').val(),
    eventName: 'mouseenter',
    onBeforeShow: function(){
        $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
        make_hover()
    },
    onChange: function(formated, dates){
        $('#inputDate').val(formated);
        make_hover()
    }
})
```

[Example](http://mfirdaus.net/random/so/datepicker.html#)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only until the calendar is changed to another month of year, then hover stops working.

Comment: The plugin in keeps on changing the DOM so we need to keep on running make_hover. Think I have a fix for that for one calendar, but modifying your fiddle made it a bit unpredictable. I'll update my answer, but i'll look into your fiddle a bit.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
<div id="date_div">
     <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="Hover Me"/>
    <div id="datePicker"></div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dat){
          $('#test').val(dat);
       }
    });
    $('#datePicker').hide();

    $('#date_div').hover(function(){
         $('#datePicker').fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
         $('#datePicker').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
</script>
```

check demo @: http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/ZVf48/4/

include jQuery and jQuery UI libraries also..

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegation on hover the dates elments, if so force a click on the element itself.

Code:

```
$("body").delegate(".datepickerDays td span","hover",function(e){
    $(this).click();
})
```

Since I can't let the plugin works on newer versions of jQuery I have to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/fFc7h/

Comment: Is that (`delegate`) the only codeblock I need to add? Cause its not working for me, any other changes that I'm missing?

Comment: @Nimbuz check the fiddle, it works; what jQuery and plugin version are you using?

Comment: @Nimbuz I'm checking it

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward @Nimbuzz When I used jQuery 1.10.x plugin broke. Which was why I used 1.3.x, but looking into turns out, plugin is using `$.curCss` which was deprecated in 1.8. So using 1.7.x worked  without changing plugin and it should have `delegate` or even `on`. Hm. Should update my answer.

Comment: @Nimbuz I must to know what you want to do; the plugin take a range after a click on two elements, a third click rapresents a new range start. The same happens in this code: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zkKpY/ because the hover rapresents a click. So what is the desired effect on hover? Always enalrge/restrict the range?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward No, the click part is ok, but I need the dates in the input fields to change on hover. Please see http://www.kayak.co.in .. if you hover on a date its updated in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use eventName 'mouseover' instead of 'hover'

Answer (score -1):

As what I have seen in the optional parameters given by the DatePicker plugin, there's no onHover function for the plugin.

However, if you have a copy of the code that generates the DatePicker, you could actually add your own .hover() method of jquery in the plugin to trigger when the mouse enters the element / plugin.

Here is the documentation for the .hover() method.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/