# Datepicker calendar hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a datepicker in my html. 
I want to display some message (alert) when hovering over any area in the datepicker calendar (not only the dates themselve)
How can i do it?

Comment: You can add a title="Your Message" if its not dynamic message.

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772962/jquery-datepicker-get-date-on-hover